# WPF Datagrid rows do not get cleared - C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `datagrid`;`Printreport` populated via an `observable collection`; `PopulatePatternData`
It runs fine and all rows are displayed when the program is run. 
When the program is rerun, I would like to get the datagrid updated with the new data rows but instead new data gets added with the previous results (rows)

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="PrintReport" ItemsSource="{Binding PopulatePatternData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="12" CanUserSortColumns="False"
                                                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"  AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro"  AlternationCount="1" 
                                                     SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Cell" >
```

The button (RunAnalysis) that I use to run the program has an `event handler`. I clear the `observable collection` when it is clicked and then the datagrid is created. 
I tried to "`clear`" the datagrid rows as shown below but to no avail.

```
 private void RunAnalysis(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WFPlanningCompliancePluginModel model = DataContext as WFPlanningCompliancePluginModel;
            model.PopulatePatternData.Clear();
            PrintReport.Items.Clear();   // This does not work         
            model.Run();
        }
```

The `collection` gets cleared but not the `datagrid`! what am i dong wrong?
The program fails when it is run the first time if I use

```
PrintReport.Items.Clear(); as it does not find any items.
```

Comment: If the binding works correctly, you don't need PrintReport.Items.Clear(); - Can you show code of the Model?

Comment: If you are clearing database table then you need to refresh you datagrid again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebind the `DataGrid` after clearing the items:

```
private void RunAnalysis(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WFPlanningCompliancePluginModel model = DataContext as WFPlanningCompliancePluginModel;
    model.PopulatePatternData.Clear();

    // PrintReport.Items.Clear();   // This you can skip if the binding works.
    PrintReport.DataBind(); // This should be enough if the binding works correctly!
    model.Run();
}
```